# Custom Callback with mySql Trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out, if or how it would be possible to implement some custom call back written in C that would get called when a table row was inserted, deleted or updated. The background is, that I have to implement some kind of view to specific data tables and one easy and generic approach would be to implement some kind of triggers, that can call a C function.

Polling is not really an option and changing the design is cause the next thing to do, if I'm confident that what I'm trying to do is not feasible.

BTW: Might this be doable with an Oracle DB?

Comment: Refer this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: @shubhansh thanks, that where the information I've searched for. It looks like that I have to have access to the server and must implement this on the DB-Server side. I was hopping to be able to "missuse" the DB as middleware ;-)